# World space view direction in Cg geometry shader

Tags: transformation, gpu, cg, geometry-shader

How to to get view direction in world space inside the Cg geometry shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be in the view matrix. Depending on your column-major or column-minor ordering, it will be in viewXf[3].xyz or flaot3(viewXf[0].w,viewXf[1].w,viewXf[2].w). Negate as desired to match your other math.